# Why does pandas.apply() work differently for Series and DataFrame columns

Tags: pandas

apologies if this is a silly question, but I am not quite sure as to why this behavior is the case, and/or whether I am misunderstanding it. I was trying to create a function for the 'apply' method, and noticed that if you run apply on a series the series is passed as a np.array and if you pass the same series within a dataframe of 1 column, the series is passed as a series to the (u)func.

This affects the way a simpleton like me writes the function (i prefer iloc indexing to integer-based indexing on the array) so I was wondering whether this is on purpose, or historical accident?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide data and a minimum code example that replicates what you mean by differently.